# Fetch Contact Name from Case

Tags: soql

I need to fetch a contact name based on whether a field in account is true and picklist field in contact is 'update' for a case.

I am writing a query that will fetch the data from account, contact and case. Below is the query I've written so far:

```
SELECT Id, AccountId, Account.Name, owner.name, CaseNumber FROM Case 
where Account.checkbox = true and contact.status = 'update'
```

Comment: Above query will work just include `contact.Name` in the SOQL to fetch Contact Name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have Checkbox field in Account as `IsChecked__c` and Picklist field on Contact as `Status__c`.

An example query to fetch cases where Account's IsChecked field is check and Contact's Status field is Started:

```
SELECT Id, CaseNumber, Contact.Name FROM Case WHERE
    Account.IsChecked__c = true AND
    Contact.Status__c = 'Started'
```

> Add **Contact.Name** in the fields you are retrieving so that you can
>   use that in your code.